# get rid/ hide/ remove the "with selected" view from modelview in flask-admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

Please advise how to get rid of "with selected" view in flask-admin Modelview. I want to completely hide it/ remove it....

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first way is to disable all the actions suggested in this dropdown menu thanks to the [`action_disallowed_list`](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.action_disallowed_list) attribute inside the `ModelView`.:

```
action_disallowed_list = ['delete']
```

This way allows to keep the individual delete/trash buttons available.

If you need to know the names of all other actions, you can call the next method inside an overridden or new method (it needs an instance)

```
print(self.get_actions_list())
```

---

Another way is to set the attribute [`can_delete = False`](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.can_delete) inside the `ModelView`.

Note that the checkboxes and the trash buttons will be hidden too.

Comment: thank you I know this one, but I want to keep the trash bins located near edit button

Comment: nice one, gg! well played!